# method to rout rope beading in door trim - rope bit or side cutting

Tags: woodworking, trim, routers, trim-carpentry

I am realizing that the $39.95 package of beaded door trim and corner rosettes amounts to 86.00 per door, and with about 10 doors to do, I've decided to mill them myself, thank you very much.  I found a great site for purchasing the rosettes, so that leaves the beaded (rope, I think, see image) trim.  **I measured and THOSE BEADS are 15/32" WIDE and about 3/32" deep.**

I realize I can buy a rope cutting bit (but I'm not sure if that's the correct term or where to buy by dimensions), or I can buy something like the image below for cutting against the side, however the flat part next to the shank would be in the way if the ropes were to butt up against each other, so that's not really the bit I need.

Question is, which method should I use, and can someone suggest a part number exact part name for the type of bit I'd use.  I am leaning to the second method but appreciate an experienced voice.  However, this post is about the correct name for either bit so I know how to find it.  This would be milled from clear pine.  Thanks!

[image: side-by-side rope - 15/32" wide]

[image: cross-section - 3/32" deep]

[image: edging bit - but top and bottom would need to be pinpoints, no flats...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device you are showing is a router bit, for making ONE shape on the edge of a piece of wood. The moulding you want is made with a completely different tool called a "spindle moulder" that would have multiple knives in that shape to make that in one pass.

Comment: A spindle moulder isn't really "a completely different tool" - it's just a bigger, table-mounted, router.  It's the difference between a dovetail saw and a panel saw, rather than a difference in kind.

Answer (score 1):

As J. Raefield has explained, the modern way to make that moulding is with a spindle moulder.  Unfortunately it's going to be much cheaper to buy the moulding ready-made than it is to buy a spindle-moulder.  They are professional machines that often need a 20A three-phase power supply.

The traditional hand-tool for creating these is a moulding plane, specifically a reed moulding plane.  You might try searching for that.  (I couldn't find any modern planes to buy, only antiques.)

Answer (score 0):

$860 to trim out 10 doors? I'd say that's not a bad deal. I did a single doorway recently using oak 1x4, 1x6, and L trim and it was over $400.

If you still want to make it, can you get a joiner and appropriate blades? Just asking...